# 502 Proxy error when connecting a GIT repo with Openproject

Tags: git, project-management

I've recently installed Openproject in a Linux box (Ubuntu 14.04) and I wanted to link a Project to an already existing GIT (bare) repository. To do this I've followed the configuration instructions:

[image: Configuration screen]

However, when I try to access the repository I get a 502 Proxy error such as the one shown in the picture. (I wonder if it has something to do with the Path encoding...)

[image: Error message]

Since I am not a system admin, I am a bit lost on where to start looking to solve this problem (Apache log? Openproject log?...). I would really appreciate any hint or tip you guys could give me.

Many thanks!

Miquel

Comment: Link to OpenProject https://www.openproject.org/

Comment: There is already a solution in the OpenProject forums...
See: https://community.openproject.com/topics/4129